# Getting the increment count based on the properties

Tags: javascript

I need to increase the count based on the property boolean which relies in two different objects or more

```js
const response = {
  address_details: {
    is_completed: true
  },
  contact_details: {
    home_details: {
      is_done_and_verified: true
    }
  }
}

const addressCount = response.address_details.is_completed ? 1 : 0
const contactCount = response.contact_details.home_details.is_done_and_verified ? 1 : 0
const count = addressCount + contactCount
console.log(count)
```

Since the key is different in the objects and nesting is different i won't be able to loop so is there any better way to get the count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const response = {
  address_details: {
    is_completed: true,
  },
  contact_details: {
    home_details: {
      is_done_and_verified: true,
    }
  }
};
const count = Object.keys(response)
  .reduce( (acc, key ) =>
     acc + (+response[key].is_completed ||
       +response[key].home_details.is_done_and_verified), 0);
       
console.log(count);
```

A more flexible way may be to use my small [`pathFinder` library](https://github.com/KooiInc/pathfinder). See [this jsfiddle](https://kooi.dev/showFiddle/ac1jkwLu) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an object of unknown structure. You want to increment value of count by every boolean type variable.

Here is solution

```html
const response = {
    address_details: {
        is_completed: true
    },
    contact_details: {
        home_details: {
            is_done_and_verified: true
        }
    }
};

let count = 0;

function test(object) {
    const values = Object.values(object);
    for (let value of values) {
        if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
            count += value;
        } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
            test(value);
        }
    }
}

test(response);
console.log(count);
```